# Angular 2 md-select external open

Tags: angular

How am I able to open a md-select from a button like this code?

```
<md-select placeholder="Cuestionario" (ngModelChange)="set_survey($event)">
   <option [ngValue]='undefined' disabled selected>Selecciona un Cuestionario</option>
   <md-option *ngFor="let survey of surveys" [value]="survey.id">{{ survey.nombre }}</md-option>
</md-select>


<button (click)="md-select.open()"></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope `md-select` is angular material component,

If it is, try below,

```
<md-select #surveyselector placeholder="Cuestionario" (ngModelChange)="set_survey($event)">
   <option [ngValue]='undefined' disabled selected>Selecciona un Cuestionario</option>
   <md-option *ngFor="let survey of surveys" [value]="survey.id">{{ survey.nombre }}</md-option>
</md-select>


<button (click)="surveyselector.open()"></button>
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/oQiziC7ck94YNOXMCwWl?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but I think this will work.

```
<md-select #mdSelect placeholder="Cuestionario" (ngModelChange)="set_survey($event)">
   <option [ngValue]='undefined' disabled selected>Selecciona un Cuestionario</option>
   <md-option *ngFor="let survey of surveys" [value]="survey.id">{{ survey.nombre }}</md-option>
</md-select>


<button (click)="mdSelect.open()"></button>
```